# Android Studio - {com.example.a5enotes/com.example.a5enotes.MainActivity} does not exist

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle

I'm working on an android application for university. I've set up my UI and was trying to get my Navigation to work, but when I run my project I'm shown the following error.

I don't know if it's because I renamed the folder or not, I'm pretty new to using android studio, so I'm not all that sure on what the error means.

```
Install successfully finished in 307 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.a5enotes/com.example.a5enotes.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Error while executing: am start -n "com.example.a5enotes/com.example.a5enotes.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.a5enotes/.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.example.a5enotes/com.example.a5enotes.MainActivity} does not exist.

Error while Launching activity
```

Comment: I usually fix this issue by doing Invalidate Cache & Restart. Can you try this?

Comment: @nuhkoca  Aright I gave Cache & restart, It comes back with the same error as before.

Comment: I see. Can you also do Clean & Rebuild Project and try again? If it doesn't work, either then I am sorry I can't help you about this.